# PHP API (SOAP nor REST) Triggered Send Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, php

I've tried this:

```
$url = "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:ac_alerts/send";    
$content = json_encode('"To": {"Address": "example@example.com", "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com"}');

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

And I've tried this:

```
require('https://autoconnect.aaa.biz/wp-content/themes/goliath-child/exacttarget_soap_client.php');

$wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';

try{
    /* Create the Soap Client */
    $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

    /* Set username and password
    * 
    *  here */
    $client->username = 'Ommitted for privacy!';
    $client->password = 'Ommitted for privacy!';

    $ts = new ExactTarget_TriggeredSend();
    $tsd = new ExactTarget_TriggeredSendDefinition();
    $tsd->CustomerKey = "ac_alerts";

    $sub = new ExactTarget_Subscriber();
    $sub->EmailAddress = "znolette@national.aaa.com";
    $sub->SubscriberKey = "znolette@national.aaa.com";

    $ts->Subscribers = $sub;    $ts->TriggeredSendDefinition = $tsd;

    $object = new SoapVar($ts, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'TriggeredSend', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

    var_dump($object);
    echo "<br><br>";
    $request = new ExactTarget_CreateRequest();
    $request->Options = NULL;
    $request->Objects = array($object);

    $results = $client->Create($request);

    var_dump($results);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Neither seems to do ANYTHING. I have no idea where to go from here. Any ideas? Even on just how to output some error code? I'm running these functions after submitting a form on a WordPress site.

Comment: A few questions: Is the Triggered Send Definitions started in the SFMC application?  If so, do the emails show as completed or error?  What's the target list/data extension of the Triggered Send Definition?  Are you supplying all of the required attributes for those?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs It is started and running, but it doesn;t show anything. No errors, queued, or completes. The list is define within the application and is already populated with subscribers. It only requires email, sub id, firstName, lastName. I tried adding the name fields, but it still doesn't do anything. I thought I might add that the ONLY things I have done to set this up were adding the exacttarget_soap_client.php file to my server and then running this code on form submit. I called ET support and they couldn't help, but mentioned defining an end point?

Comment: Are you using the correct WSDL for your account?

Comment: What happens if you use something like Postman to trigger the send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out there were SO many issues with my code:

1. Wrong directory was referenced for require()
2. Necessary files were not present on server. The only files needed are listed below and can be found [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/Global/Documentation/APIStarterKits/PHP%20APIstarterKit-V1.zip) within "PHP/00 Includes".

   1. exacttarget_soap_client.php
   2. soap-wsse.php
   3. xmlseclibs.php
3. Triggered Send was created in a business line account, but this account was not referenced in the code
4. Purpose of this project was to trigger a send to an entire list, but Triggered Send only sends to ONE user and gives the option to add that user to a list. A User Initiated Send was created in GUI (in the default/parent account!) instead.

Here's my final code:

```
require('/CORRECT/SERVER/REFERENCE/LOCATION/THIS/TIME/wp-content/themes/goliath-child/includes/exacttarget_soap_client.php');

$wsdl = 'https://webservice.exacttarget.com/etframework.wsdl';

if($entry['7'] == "4"){ //This is logic to control when I want to initiate the send
    try{
        /* Create the Soap Client */
        $client = new ExactTargetSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1));

        /* Set username and password */
        $client->username = 'ET MC USERNAME';
        $client->password = 'ET MC PASSWORD';

        $pr = new ExactTarget_PerformRequestMsg();
        $pr->Action = "start";   
        $pr->Definitions =  array();

        $def = new ExactTarget_EmailSendDefinition();
        $def->CustomerKey = "ac_alerts"; //Already existing User Initated Send defined within the GUI of ET

        $pr->Definitions[] = new SoapVar($def, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'EmailSendDefinition', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        $pr->Options = NULL;

        $results = $client->Perform($pr);  

        var_dump($results); //This was not working for me until I enabled PHP DEBUG mode in WordPress

    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        var_dump($e); //This was not working for me until I enabled PHP DEBUG mode in WordPress
    }
}
```